# How can I aggregate/pivot this non-numeric data to show in a chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

I'd like to show some data on a line chart. The source data looks like this:

```
[
        {
          date: 1,
          depth: 1,
          river: 'trent',
        },
        {
          date: 1,
          depth: 7,
          river: 'severn',
        },
        {
          date: 2,
          depth: 5,
          river: 'severn',
        },
        {
          date: 2,
          depth: 3,
          river: 'trent',
        },
]
```

I'd like the chart to:

- have **date** as an x axis (1-2)
- have **depth** as the y axis (1-7)
- have **two lines**, one for each river ("severn" and "trent")

So, I need to aggregate ("pivot"?) each data point based on the name of the river.

```
[
      {
        date: 1,
        'trent.depth': 1,
        'severn.depth': 7,
      },
      {
        date: 2,
        'trent.depth': 5,
        'severn.depth': 3,
      },
]
```

I know some combination of `map`, `filter` and `reduce` to do this, but I'm finding it a little mind-bending.

What's the best way to do this, *firstly* as a one off, and *then* in a general, repeatable way that isn't specific to river depth over time, where I might pass in the following as arguments to a function:

- the source data (as above)
- the axis that should be the
- one (or more!) y axis as data series
- one (or more!) axes to break down/aggregate data by

For context, I'm using [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/) to display my data if that matters.

So far I've got something like:

```js
const prepareChartData = (sourceData, xAxis, yAxes, aggregateBy) => {

  return entityData.map((row) => {
    // recharts expects x axis to be called 'name'
    const point = {
      name = row[xAxis]
    }

    // fill in remaining data
    yAxes.forEach((axis) => {
      if (!aggregateBy?.length) {
        point[axis] = row[axis]
      } else {
        // for each breakdown field
        aggregateBy.forEach((breakdown) => {
          // all the values this breakdown field holds
          const uniqueVals = new Set(...entityData.map((row) => row[breakdown]))
          // for every single value in the breakdown...
          for (const breakdownVal in uniqueVals) {
                   point[`${breakdown}.${}`] = // ???????
          }
        })
      }
    })
    return point
  })
}
```

It's a long way from working obviously.

---

For second-order aggregations, input data like:

```
[
        {
          date: 1,
          depth: 1,
          river: 'trent',
          county: 'south',
        },
        {
          date: 1,
          depth: 7,
          river: 'severn',
          county: 'north',
        },
        {
          date: 2,
          depth: 7,
          river: 'trent',
          county: 'south',
        },
        {
          date: 2,
          depth: 5,
          river: 'severn',
          county: 'north',
        },
        {
          date: 2,
          depth: 3,
          river: 'trent',
          county: 'north',
        },
      ]
```

Should give an output like:

```
[
      {
        name: 1,
        'trent.south.depth': 1,
        'severn.north.depth': 7,
      },
      {
        name: 2,
        'trent.north.depth': 3,
        'trent.south.depth': 7,
        'severn.north.depth': 5,
      },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for your data

```js
const data = [{
    date: 1,
    depth: 1,
    river: 'trent',
  },
  {
    date: 1,
    depth: 7,
    river: 'severn',
  },
  {
    date: 2,
    depth: 5,
    river: 'severn',
  },
  {
    date: 2,
    depth: 3,
    river: 'trent',
  },
]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((res, {date, depth, river}) => {
   const existing = res[date] || {date}
   res[date] = {...existing, [river+'.depth']: depth}
   return res
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

A more general approach could be

```js
const prepareChartData = (sourceData, xAxis, yAxes, aggregateBy) => 
  Object.values(sourceData.reduce((res, item) => {
    const key = item[xAxis]
    const existing = res[key] || {[xAxis]: key}
    return {
     ...res,
     [key]: {
       ...existing,
       ...Object.fromEntries(yAxes.flatMap((valueKey) =>
         aggregateBy.map(prefixKey =>[[item[prefixKey], valueKey].join('.'), item[valueKey] ] )
       ))
     }
    }
  
  }, {}))
  
  
  const data = [{
    date: 1,
    depth: 1,
    river: 'trent',
    length: 12
  },
  {
    date: 1,
    depth: 7,
    river: 'severn',
    length: 13
  },
  {
    date: 2,
    depth: 5,
    river: 'severn',
     length: 47
  },
  {
    date: 2,
    depth: 3,
    river: 'trent',
    length: 63
  },
]
console.log(prepareChartData(data, 'date', ['depth', 'length'], ['river']))
```

Comment: that's great! it almost does exactly what i need, but i think the correct behaviour for multiple aggregators would be to treat them recursively as aggregations of aggregations, rather than on the same level, which i think this implementation does.

i think a good example would be adding, say, sample area as another key to each data point.

Comment: @parasomnist I wasn't sure of the format you wanted so I guessed... if you want to add some examples of desired output format I can try another approach

Comment: oh hey! i've added an example of the output i'm trying to achieve, does that make sense?